# FB Graph API redirect on login isn't working

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am currently running a facebook app on a django server. The index page is at `localhost:8000/b/` and its contents are:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div id='fb-root'></div>
  <button id='login-container' class="btn" ng-click="myFacebookLogin()">Login with Facebook</button>
</body>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var app = angular.module('mainApp', [])
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myFacebookLogin = function () {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      console.log(response)
      if (response.status !== 'connected') {
        FB.login(function() {}, {scope: ['user_about_me', 'user_status']})
      }
    })
  }
})

$(document).ready( function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true })
  $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: 'APP-ID',
      version: 'v2.3' // or v2.0, v2.1, v2.0
    })
  })
})
</script>
</html>
```

In my app settings on facebook I have set `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` to `http://localhost:8000/b/redir` but the redirect doesn't happen. the same page is still shown after the user is logged in. This can be verified by clicking on the login button again and seeing the reponse received. How do I fix this? Should I manually redirect the user or should I have tweak smoething on facebook?

FWIW, using `location.href = '/b/redir'` after successful login does the job. I'm just wondering what the correct way is!

Comment: Specifying a `redirect_uri` in your app settings does not mean that any automatic redirects will happen on your page when the user logs in. (That is only for specifying valid URLs that the user _can_ be redirected to from the FB login dialog, if you actually use the redirect version. But when using the JS SDK for login, that doesn’t directly apply.). If you want a redirect to happen, then you will have to do it yourself, in the callback functions for `FB.getLoginStatus` or `FB.login`.

Comment: @CBroe - Oh! Good to know that I had it right. Just wanted to make sure that something doesn't break in the future. I'll leave the question up, in case someone gets the same doubt in the future!